# How to purge old Openshot files?

Tags: apt, 22.04, snap, flatpak, purge

I want a fresh install of Openshot using its latest Linux(64-bit AppImage) file on a machine that had previously installed Openshot via apt, snap and flatpak. I have purged all its old installations. I have even purged flatpak. However, I still found Openshot files on this machine and its thumbnail appears in the Ubuntu 22.04 applications grid.

```
$ sudo apt list | grep openshot

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

libopenshot-audio-dev/jammy 0.2.0+dfsg1-4 amd64
libopenshot-audio-doc/jammy,jammy 0.2.0+dfsg1-4 all
libopenshot-audio-test-sound/jammy 0.2.0+dfsg1-4 amd64
libopenshot-audio7/jammy 0.2.0+dfsg1-4 amd64
libopenshot-dev/jammy 0.2.5+dfsg1-6build2 amd64
libopenshot-doc/jammy,jammy 0.2.5+dfsg1-6build2 all
libopenshot19/jammy 0.2.5+dfsg1-6build2 amd64
openshot-qt-doc/jammy,jammy 2.5.1+dfsg1-2 all
openshot-qt/jammy,jammy 2.5.1+dfsg1-2 all
python3-openshot/jammy 0.2.5+dfsg1-6build2 amd64

$ sudo apt purge openshot
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package 'openshot' is not installed, so not removed
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libappstream-glib8 libmalcontent-0-0 libostree-1-1
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.

$ sudo apt purge openshot-qt
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package 'openshot-qt' is not installed, so not removed
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libappstream-glib8 libmalcontent-0-0 libostree-1-1
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.

$ dpkg -l | grep openshot

$ flatpak
bash: /usr/bin/flatpak: No such file or directory
```

However, according to Nautilus, many residual files are in the `/var/lib/flatpak/app` directory.

[image: residual openshot files]

Also, the Openshot thumbnail continues to exist in the Applications grid

[image: openshot thumbnail in Applications grid]

but folders `~/.local/share/applications` and `/usr/share/applications` do not contain any openshot `.desktop` files.

**Questions**:

1. Can I simply delete the folder `/var/lib/flatpak/app/org.openshot.OpenShot` and not cause any problem to the machine?
2. Since I have purged flatpak, can I even delete folder `/var/lib/flatpak`?
3. Also, how do I remove the Openshot thumbnail in the Applications grid?

**Update:**

I discovered the existence of a file called `org.openshot.OpenShot.desktop`. It's paths are:

- `/var/lib/flatpak/app/org.openshot.OpenShot/x86_64/stable/a3e062afc67b6bcba4c61fffa4a9c7d4baab1fb0843f99b8f79e2497e15bc42e/export/share/applications/org.openshot.OpenShot.desktop`
- `/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share/applications/org.openshot.OpenShot.desktop`

This terminal command removed the Openshot thumbnail from the Applications grid:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/flatpak/exports/share/applications/org.openshot.OpenShot.desktop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To purge all old Openshot files from this machine, I concluded that all files or folders related with/to `org.openshot.OpenShot` had to be removed. To remove the relevant directories I performed `sudo rm -r <dir-path>` and to remove relevant files I performed `rm <file-path>`. Nautilus can be used to search the root directory to reveal the paths of all openshot files.
2. Since I have purged flatpak, the folder `/var/lib/flatpak` could be removed too.
3. This terminal command to removed the Openshot thumbnail from the Applications grid was `sudo rm /var/lib/flatpak/exports/share/applications/org.openshot.OpenShot.desktop`